# Detect HTML5 Media Capture API Support

Tags: html, api, media, capture

Is there a way to detect whether a browser supports the HTML5 Media Capture API for a mobile website I'm building? I can only seem to find solutions for detecting `getUserMedia()` support.

I would like to be able to present mobile users one of two scenarios:

- User's browser supports the API, so two upload buttons are displayed, one activating the camera and one activating the image gallery.
- User's browser doesn't support the API, so just one upload buttons is displayed, hopefully activating the gallery if their browser supports the accept parameter.

Comment: I'm confused. Why aren't the solution for checking for getusermedia support acceptable?

Comment: Isn't `getUserMedia()` a different API to Media Capture? For example: Chrome supports `getUserMedia()` and can display images and video from my webcam natively, but if I use the following HTML: `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`, I can't capture an image from my webcam to upload to my web server.

Comment: Ah - you are correct. Sorry - I keep forgetting about that particular form of capture.

Comment: Actually - I believe getUserMedia is the 'real' API and this was the old version. Check the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/media-capture-api/ It says specifically work on the spec is dead and getUserMedia is what is being used for the future.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I suppose the question now is; can I use `getUserMedia()` to trigger system dialogues in the same way as you could with the media capture API? `getUserMedia()` seems to focus on embedding media capture into the web page. In an ideal world I'm trying to replicate the PhoneGap camera function: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: The original Media Capture API linked to above is indeed deprecated, but was replaced by both the getUserMedia() API and a new HTML Media Capture API ( http://www.w3.org/TR/capture-api/ ). The difference is the old one was a more complicated JavaScript API whereas the new one is a single HTML attribute (so no JavaScript required). Regarding detection, I've been looking into it but can't find a solution. There seems to be no way to programmatically detect for "capture" attribute support, sadly.

Comment: Made a little snippet for that, since all the alternatives seems to fail: https://gist.github.com/rafaelrinaldi/5969890

Answer (score 3):

> User's browser supports the API, so two upload buttons are displayed, one activating the camera and one activating the image gallery.

There's no way (at the moment) to create 2 separate HTML buttons: one for (just) the library & one for (just) the camera (
I've covered all the possible HTML Media Capture options in [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/))

Use
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;">` and you'll be prompted to choose between capturing a photo or selecting an existing one:

[image]

> User's browser doesn't support the API, so just one upload buttons is displayed, hopefully activating the gallery if their browser supports the accept parameter

**Support is as follows:**

- Android 2.2+ and iOS6.0+ support the above code
- Android 3.0+ supports `capture` and takes the user straight to the camera
- iOS6 through 10 do NOT support `capture` (prompt is always shown)
- desktop browsers do NOT support HTML Media Capture

Detecting support resumes to detecting the above browsers.

Support reference: [this 2013 O'Reilly book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=gswdarRZVUoC&pg=PA263&dq=%22file+upload+compatibility+table%22) and [my testing](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), [on the docs page](https://modernizr.com/docs) you can see in the [table of features supported and detected](https://modernizr.com/docs#features) that they detect both the [HTML Media Capture](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/74655c45ad2cd05c002e4802cdd74cba70310f08/feature-detects/forms/capture.js) and also the [getUserMedia](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/74655c45ad2cd05c002e4802cdd74cba70310f08/feature-detects/webrtc/getusermedia.js)