# How to check HTML5 Image capture in mobile Device?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [HTML5 Image Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) for capturing images in mobile.I want to check the support is available for the image capture in mobile device or not.Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: Can't mark this as a duplicate as the other question didn't get answered, but here you go none the less: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070555/detect-browser-support-for-html-media-capture

Comment: @C-linkNepal: If you believe that feature is available in modernizr it would be useful if you pointed out how it's called.

Comment: @DavidMulder I don't know about image capture. So, I can't answer.

Comment: can i check like this if(typeof (window.FileReader) == undefined)

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/forms/capture.js This feature isn't implemented in any browser yet. Don't use! Wait for some month.